# reusing sql queries in different routes

Tags: python, sql, bottle

I am new in `python`. Using the bottle framework I have two routes as below

```
@app.route("/foo/:slug")
def foo(slug):
    # execute heavy sql query here
    sql = "..."


@app.route("/bar/:slug")
def bar(slug):
    # again execute the heavy sql query ...
    sql = "..."
```

As you can see in above routes I execute the same query redundantly, but this looks ugly to me, is there a way to execute such a query once and then reuse it in another route?

NOTE: Answers without using `global` variables will be appreciated.

Comment: Write helper functions.

Comment: calling the helper function multiple times will not execute the query multiple times?

Comment: That depends on the helper function. It could cache the query result and return the cached result for the second call.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap it inside models object for example :

```
import models    

@app.route("/foo/:slug")
def foo(slug):
    data = models.heavy_data()


@app.route("/bar/:slug")
def bar(slug):
    data = models.heavy_data()
```

and models can cache the data with [memcache](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymemcache)